# Finding total eth amount sent to contract from address

Tags: web3js, erc-20

I am implementing a simple tokensale platform using web3.js.

It should display to the user 'You have already sent us 2.3 ETH and recieved 1003 tokens'.

It is easy to find out how many tokens the user has by using balanceOf(), but how can I find how much ETH that user sent to the contract. I can't calculate it based on tokens held, because the rate would change.

In the contract I have:

```
mapping (address => uint256) public amountPurchased;
```

I am currently using:

```
contractAbi = JSON.parse('[{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"amountPurchased","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]');

var crowdsaleContract = web3.eth.contract(contractAbi);

var crowdsale = crowdsaleContract.at('[TOKENSALE ADDRESS]');

crowdsale.amountPurchased.call(userAddress, function(err, result){
  alert(result);
});
```

but the result is always 0

Comment: either by reading the log or by adding the recived ethers in your payable fct

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `mapping(address => uint) spendByAddress` to capture total spend (in Wei) and increase this total every time a user sends ether to your payable function. When new donations are received you could then query `spendByAddress[msg.sender]` to return the total amount of Ether received from that address.

The same approach could be used to map total token allocation too, so you keep track of how many tokens they've received over time, even if they've sold/transferred them elsewhere after they bought them from you.

Comment: I have a mapping like this in my contract. I have updated my original post to show how I am trying to access it, thanks.

Comment: in your ABI you're defining `amountPurchased` but in your script you're calling `totalPurchase` - try calling `amountPurchased` instead

Comment: ah yeh, I noticed that, it has been changed now, but still same result. Not sure what else the issue could be.

Comment: 1. Try checking for errors with `if(!error) {alert(result)} else {alert(error)}` and see if something else is the issue here, and 2. Your ABI doesn't include any payable functions (or any other functions, for that matter) - have you successfully sent the contract any Ether for the result to actually be >0?

Comment: I have tried that but it returns no error. I only need to read the 1 mapping so I don't need the full ABI, right?

Comment: you only need the partial ABI for this section of your code - I just wanted to check you weren't using the same ABI to try and do anything else with the contract! Have you logged any events which show your token balance is >0 for the account in question? it may help if you add your contract code so we can see how `amountPurchased` is supposed to be updated when users make a deposit